# dayjs - not a function

Tags: javascript, date, dayjs

I'm passing two dayjs date to Vars.date global variables.

```
var dayjs = require("dayjs") for import
   
Vars.date1 = dayjs(whateverdate1("add", 2)).format('MMM D, YYYY')
Vars.date2 = dayjs(whateverdate2("add", 2)).format('MMM D, YYYY')

const date1 = Vars.date1
const date2 = Vars.date2
let diff = date1.diff(date2, 'month')
console.log('diff' + diff)
```

error: TypeError: date1.diff is not a function

I am unable to use diff and get methods, always 'not a function'

What did I miss?

Comment: What is Vars.date? Where are you getting it from? Can you console log date2 and date1 so I can see what heir values are?

Comment: `diff` is available on dayjs object. From your code, your have `Vars.date` which we have no info on, plus I don't think it is an instance of DayJS object, hence, this error.

Comment: Sorry guys, @ImDarkk I missed those lines. I edited my original question. It seems to me, those are dayjs objects...

Comment: It turned out, Vars.date was not a dayjs object, as you guys mentioned. I guessed the Vars.date = dayjs(whatever) returns a dayjs object, but it seems not. using dayjs method on that solved the problem. I wanna accept an answer, please post it and will accept it. thanks

Comment: @brobee You should be allowed to answer and accept your own question

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that *Day.js* supports the `require()` function. If it is `import`-based, you need to maybe change the import to that.

So, just try doing the following.

```js
import dayjs from "dayjs";
```

### Links

- [*npm* Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dayjs)
- [Official *Day.js* website](https://day.js.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you had two problems:

1. `add()` should be called like `dayjs().add(2, 'month')`
2. Your were trying to call `diff()` on a string (the output of `dayjs().format()`) rather than a `Dayjs` object

Here's how you can create two dayjs objects and find their difference in months:

```js
const dayjs = require("dayjs")
// or:
// import dayjs from "dayjs";

const date1 = dayjs()   // Dayjs object of current month
const date2 = dayjs().add(2, "month") // Dayjs object of 2 months from now

date2.diff(date1, "month") // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If Your Day.js supports the require() function then use

```
var dayjs = require("dayjs")
```

or its support import so you use this

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
```